# How can I prevent people from seeing my "like" activities on LinkedIn in their feeds?

Tags: privacy, linkedin

How can I prevent people from seeing my "like" activities on LinkedIn in their feeds?

[image]

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://qr.ae/pXZ8uZ
- https://redd.it/fbiw59

Answer (score 1):

Turn it off in your settings:

Me > Settings & Privacy > How others see your profile and network information > Representing your organisation and interests (direct link: https://www.linkedin.com/psettings/meet-the-team)

Change the value to No.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that looks promising! I'll ask some connection to confirm that it works tomorrow (to make sure the cache is flushed).

Comment: What did you find, Franck?